# Yii 2 создание своего модуля?

Tags: yii2

Предположим я хочу создать свой модуль, который потом хочу грузить как вендор к любому проекту. Т.е. там будут миграции, модели и прочее, все это будет на гитхабе

Что мне для этого нужно? Скопировать сгенеренный гии модуль не вариант? Можно наглядно объяснить?

Comment: Просто совет: посмотрите как это уже реализовано у других и сделайте по примеру

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете для начала расположить свой модуль в директории common/modules/mymodule и работать с этим неймспейсом. Соответственно в конфиге добавить

```
 'modules' => [
        'mymodule' => [ 
              'class' => 'common\modules\mymodule\Module',
  ],
],
```

Затем перед релизом изменить namespace на ваш vendorname\yii2-mymodule, добавить к нему composer.json с описанием зависимостей и пр. и добавить модуль на packagist.org. После этого можно делать

```
composer require vendorname\yii2-mymodule
```